# Show that the taylor series of $\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ equals $\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Show that the taylor series of $\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ equals $\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

I have done the taylor series as follows:

$\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\sum_{n=2k+1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n}{n!}$

I have two questions:

- Is the formula right?
- how can I show that this sum is equals really $\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}$?

Comment: See this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem , you can prove in general for any $x$.

Comment: What is the Taylor series of a number ?

Comment: I am guessing you meant that the Taylor series of $\;\cos x\;$ *at* $\;x=\pi/2\;$ actually equals $\;\cos\frac\pi2=0\;$ ....anyway, what you wrote is not the Taylor series of anything as it begins from a weird, undetermined $\;n=2k+1\;$  ...Of course, if you input $\;x=\pi/2\;$ in the right side you get then a series of zeros, which equals zero...that'd be a rather strange thing.